# Append style to facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I'm trying apply a custom CSS to fb like button using this code:

```
$("#fblike").css("background-color", "red");
```

But isn't working, I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null

Is there any way to solve this? Here is my code:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1&appId=XX&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<span class="fb-like">    
  <fb:like id="fblike" name="fblike" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" 
   href="https://www.facebook.com/cocacola/"></fb:like>
</span>
```

Also, I've tried using CURL to parse my facebook page to handle elements, but still asking to login, so I'm not able to apply the CSS in this case too...

Thank you.

Comment: Are you loading your JS _after_ the dom has loaded?

Comment: Yes, of course I am

Comment: Please give us some more context by posting the rest of your code, with as little as the single line of code that is referenced in the error and the code provided by Facebook themselves we can only guess what exactly the cause of your problem is.

Comment: I didn't created any code yet, I'm just running commands on console in hope to handle facebook elements

Comment: Someone told right now that Facebook prohibited this :(. So, now I'm trying bypass it

Comment: yes, you are not allowed to change the appearence of facebooks social plugins. do not bypass it.